# Display x number of terms and exclude hidden

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, terms

I use the following code to exclude terms with hidden products. I want to display only 5 terms but when I add the parameter `number` it also take account of hidden terms so I get fewer terms depended on `orderby` parameter.

Is there any way to get any of the first 5 visible terms?

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'number' => '5',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'parent' => '11',
);

$terms = get_terms( $args );
$terms = wp_list_filter( $terms, array( 'count' => 0 ), 'NOT' );
```

Comment: You always want to search for what you want, not what you don't want. Excluding things in a query is an inherently expensive thing, requiring the DB server to look at all the content you have to compile a list of posts that need to be excluded before it can then search for posts not in that list, loading everything into memory. This doesn't happen normally. It can be orders of magnitude faster to say you want every other product category or to exclude it manually in PHP

Comment: I am trying to get the first 5 terms that have term count bigger than 0 but it also take into account the terms with 0 count. So the result is to get fewer than 5 terms. I agree with you but I don't understand how this answer my question. One way is to use `array_slice` but just wonder if there is a better solution.

Comment: These are comments, not answers, I'm still not entirely sure what you're asking, I didn't understand your previous comment 100%, when you say you want the first 5 terms, what do you mean? Terms are not ordered, do you mean alphabetically? Or the terms with the most posts? When you say taking into account those with 0, what do you mean? Can you provide an example? Please edit your question to include these details

Comment: Those with 0 is when the parameter `count` is 0. If we have 10 terms and 2 of them have 0 count I can't get 5 of them if I set the `number` parameter to 5. I will get for example 3 (it depends on what I have set in `orderby` parameter) because the other 2 have count=0.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand, is it that you don't want terms that are empty?

Answer (score 0):

Googling `get_terms` gives the [WP developer hub page for `get_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) as the first result, for which the first example is this:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'post_tag', array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```

Using this as a basis we get:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'number' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'parent' => 11,
    'hide_empty' => true,
);

$terms = get_terms( $args );
```

Comment: Just a note here, this syntax only works from v4.5

Comment: Another note: I think we should take care running `'hide_empty' => true` on hierarchical taxonomies with large number of children. Looks like we could have large number of `get_term_children` calls in that case.

Comment: Tom thank you I really appreciate your time but it didn't help me. I think the key here is that the products (woocommerce) are set to hidden. So the terms are not really empty. For example If we have one hidden product assign to the term this will set the term count to 0 that's why I use `$terms = wp_list_filter( $terms, array( 'count' => 0 ), 'NOT' );` to exclude these terms. If I use the `number` parameter it also take into account these terms so the result is fewer terms than 5. For now I get all terms and use `array_slice` I don't know if there is any more efficient way.

Comment: Ah, you should have mentioned, that complicates things greatly as this is nonstandard behaviour